# nested grid: вложенный grid

Tags: html, css, vue.js

Есть ли какие-нибудь особенности при создании nested grid?

```
<div class="grid-parent">
  <div class="grid-item">
    <div class="nested-grid">
      <div class="nested-grid-item">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Проблема в том, что вложенный грид на весь экран растягивается. Следует отметить, что вложенный грид — это отдельный компонент vuejs. И на самом деле, между ним и родительским гридом есть ещё один `<div>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В описании вопроса не совсем корректный пример. На самом деле, он такой:

parent.vue

```
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item">
    <child/>
  </div>
</div>
```

child.vue

```
 <div class="grid-container">
   <div class="grid-item">
   </div>
 </div>
```

В таком случае, оказывается, что в child.vue используются стили из родительского компонента. Но не из компонента-брата.